# Is there a keyboard shortcut to dismiss the intellisense panel (vscode)?

Tags: visual-studio-code

sometimes I want to hide the intellisense panel. I can do it with a click, but is there a way to do it with the keyboard?

Answer (score 10):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>space</kbd> toggles the intellisense in the suggest widget. This is bound to the `toggleSuggestionDetails` command.

To dismiss the the suggest widget itself, press <kbd>esc</kbd> which is bound to the `hideSuggestWidget` command.

You can customize these shortcuts with [keybindings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings)