# how to close this window

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

[image]

when i study python in the vscode, there is a hover tip window(unclear whether the right name) that unexpectedly appear. When I click on it, it copies the code "dict2" and paste it into the code just like 'dict2dit2' you can see inside the picture. so how to close that?

Comment: just keep typing anything but Tab or Enter

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a keyboard shortcut to dismiss the intellisense panel (vscode)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44958439/is-there-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-dismiss-the-intellisense-panel-vscode)

Answer (score 0):

Move your mouse to somewhere else.
If this doesn't work, restart VS Code.
This happened to me few times before.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it really works! It's not the first time that i have this problem.  I still don't know what causes this. But rebooting always works.

Comment: @skyless you reboot your machine to get rid of the intellisense? That's a bit of a drastic measure...

Comment: Shame for myself(not a good English learner). I mean restart the VScode.

Answer (score 0):

This is vscode [IntelliSense](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense), which provides a faster and more convenient coding method. It is generally not recommended to turn it off as it provides effective smart suggestions to make your coding more convenient.

- *https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense*
- *https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/editing#_autocomplete-and-intellisense*

Comment: Sorry, I didn't describe my question well. As you know the IntelliSense provides us tips that alphabetical sorting based, usually we just click or use keyboard arrow keys to select what we want. But what I meet is : i cant close it, even when i change to another python script, it still exists. You can't move or close it! But,  in another python script, if you click it again, it will also be pasted. So I wonder what's that?

Comment: So you think this is a bug on your machine? You need to provide more information, vscode and extended versions, etc. Describe your steps in detail so others can replicate them.